# INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE

Tags: update, insert

I try to update an object from Tibco.  While i try to do so I get the following error

INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE

I have ensured that I am updating the field directly and not through any parent relationship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error means that the field in question can't be updated as part of the API call. You'll get this error when you try to update a read-only field, such as CreatedById without Editable Audit Fields, or a master-detail field that does not allow reparenting of records. You'll want to check the field to see if it can be written to.

Comment: I second that..

Comment: Adding to this answer, I received this error setting a value to a field the user didn't have FLS access to.